# How to keep the numbers of whitspace in a line unchanged with awk?

Tags: bash, awk, whitespace

I want to get the longest line in /etc/sudoers.
For wc.

```
sudo wc -L /etc/sudoers
90 /etc/sudoers
```

For awk

```
sudo awk '{if(length>L){L=length;s=$0}}END{print NR,L,s}'  /etc/sudoers
27 83 Defaults  secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

awk treat 8 whitespaces in 27th line as just 1 whitespace,8-1=7,90-83=7.
So the numbers got with wc is 7 bigger than awk.
How to keep the numbers of whitspace in a line unchanged with awk,to make awk treat 8 whitespaces in 27th line unchanged ,instead of 1.
How to fix the command `sudo awk '{if(length>L){L=length;s=$0}}END{print NR,L,s}'  /etc/sudoers` ,to output the following result with awk.

```
27 90 Defaults  secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because the file contains tabs.

> With the `--max-line-length' option,`wc' prints the length of the
>   longest line per file, and if there is more than one file it prints
>   the maximum (not the sum) of those lengths.  The line lengths here are
>   measured in screen columns, according to the current locale and
>   assuming tab positions in every 8th column.

So wc assumes each tab to be of width 8. We have to emulate this in awk. One special case when the tab only occurs in the beginning of the line is easy to mend.

```
sudo awk '{sub("\t","        ") ; 
    if(length>L){L=length;s=$0}}END{print NR,L,s}' /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: debian@wifi:~$ sudo awk '{line=gensub("^\t","        ","1") ; 
>     if(length(line)>L){L=length(line);s=line}}END{print NR,L,s}' /etc/sudoers

Comment: awk: line 3: function gensub never defined

Comment: @it_is_a_literature  If you are not using `gawk` then `sub` should be available. Updated the command

Comment: To remove  ^ in sub("^\t","        "),the right form is as below.

Comment: sudo awk '{sub("\t","        ") ; 
    if(length>L){L=length;s=$0}}END{print NR,L,s}' /etc/sudoers

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Will keep `^\t` to be on the safe side as `wc` does not replace tabs with a fixed number of spaces but aligns to the nearest 8th column.

Comment: wrong,^ means beginning,no \t locate the begin of the line,so no sub action happen.

Comment: `sudo awk '{sub("^\t","        ") ;  if(length>L){L=length;s=$0}}END{print NR,L,s}' /etc/sudoers` is the same as `sudo awk '{if(length>L){L=length;s=$0}}END{print NR,L,s}' /etc/sudoers`

Answer (score 1):

The max length of the line in /etc/sudoers contained a tab, as you can see from the `hexdump` of the file,

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers | hexdump -C
...
...
00000110  73 73 0a 44 65 66 61 75  6c 74 73 09 73 65 63 75  |ss.Defaults.secu|
...
...
```

You may see `09` between 2 s (hex: 73). And look it into the ascii table, it would be ***horizontal tab***.

You may see from @Dmitri Chubarov's answer, `wc` would treat the length of `'\t'` as 8.

An alternative way to make `awk` output the same result as `wc -L` can be,

```
$ sudo awk '{if(length>L){L=7*(match($0,/\t/)?1:0)+length;s=$0}}END{print NR,L,s}' /etc/sudoers
30 100 Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

The function `match($0,/\t/)?1:0` would return 1 any `\t` existed, add 7 for the length if yes.